# How to use electrolytic capacitors in Orcad Capture

Tags: orcad

I want to specify voltage across the electrolytic capacitor in Orcad but there seems to be no way to this. 
I'm using `C_elect` part and the panel to choose the value is below:

[image]

I've tried this formats but none of them worked: `1u 16` `1uF 16V`

Comment: The voltage across a capacitor is determined by the circuit it's  connected to, not by a characteristic of the capacitor.

Comment: The WV rating of the cap only tells you how much voltage you can apply before the capacitor blows up.

Comment: So why is the value of capacitor specified in my project like [this] (https://imgur.com/a/MgiOdBP) @ThePhoton

Comment: Because you need a cap rated for 16 V (or higher) to avoid blowing it up in that circuit.

Comment: So I can skip specifying this voltage and go on simulating the circuit? @ThePhoton

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.

Comment: @mahdi, correct. The WV rating won't affect the simulation. Also, if you exceed the rating, the simulator will not tell you that in the real world you capacitor might have blown up.